# throws Exception correct structure?

Tags: android, exception, try-catch

Just wondering if this is a correct structure to use with try and exceptions:

```
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener videoViewCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) throws IllegalStateException {
        try {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            videoView.stopPlayback();
        } finally {
            toastDisplay.cancel();
            toastDisplay = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completed Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toastDisplay.show();
        }
    }
};
```

Will it crash my app or not when i do it this way, incase it throws the `IllegalStateException` in this example?

Comment: You should add the catch clause

Comment: Isnt there anyway to avoid using the catch clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state in your declaration that your method throws an `IllegalStateException`. However, you are never raising an exception for the caller to handle. If the exception you want to throw is caused by a `MediaPlayer` method, you need to have a `catch` block. In that, just `throw` the exception up for the caller to handle.

[image]

Also, [Exception handling : throw, throws and Throwable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940213/exception-handling-throw-throws-and-throwable) is a good read.

Comment: So its not possible to make it like i want to do it and ignore the exception? Do you mind making an example out of my example?

Comment: Yes, if you want that the app continue doing its stuff you can surround with the try only the method that may throw an exception. Then, the execution will be CODE, CODE, TRY, (if exception CATCH), CODE CODE. Sequential as ever.  You also will have to add some null control after the try/catch because of the exception maybe thrown

Comment: @MohamedAllouch well, joaquin said it (:

Comment: So in this case my example is correct? It will not crash incase the exception is thrown? Sorry my english isnt that good.

Comment: @MohamedAllouch In **your** case, if a exception is generated, it will go to the finally block without crashing. If you want to do something when an exception is thrown, like show a message or log the cause, you will need a `catch` block :)

Comment: Awesome, thats what i needed to hear :) Do i need to have the `throws IllegalStateException` that i have added in the end of the public void or is it not necessary to have in my case?

Comment: @MohamedAllouch Do you intend to throw the exception up to the caller? If not, just add a catch block and remove the `throws`.

Comment: I dont want to use a catch block, just try { } finally { }. Thank you for the help guys.

Comment: Sorry im new here, this is also my first app. How do i accept the answer? ^^

Comment: @MohamedAllouch welcome to SO :) Click on the tick mark above, to the left side of my answer.

Comment: Thank you :) unfortunately my account have been banned from asking new questions :( I am new with all this, give me a break SO :( Have a nice day my friend